# Password field on IE8.0

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a password field on one of our .aspx page. The users see the bullets on Firefox but on IE 8.0 they see square boxes. We use a fair amount of CSS processing.

Any idea why IE has a problem?

Comment: Without showing the *fair* amount of CSS you are using I highly doubt we will be able to help you. Try posting on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I haven't defined anything special for the password field in CSS. It is the standard Password Field type!

Comment: use the Developer Tools that come with IE to see what (default) styles have been applied to the password field.

Comment: @Nicholas Murray default password field style sets to sans serif @GoldenUser what is you page encoding !? try to change it to unicode !

Comment: @Synxmax: How do I change the encoding to unicode?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by setting my font on the password field to a web safe font such as Helvetica Neue.

I was using custom fonts and that seemed to cause issues in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your head

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UNICODE">
```

Comment: Thanks. I added that to the header on my Site.Master, but it still shows the squres on the password field.

Answer (score 0):

Some custom font-face fonts doesn't work well with the password field in IE8. Use a web safe font for the password input will fix your problem:

```
input[type="password"] {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```